# Achieving ArcGIS Dissolve result with GeoTools

Tags: geotools, dissolve

I want to merge two or more adjacent lines (within a XY tolerance) to one line. The result from Dissolve in ArcGIS is what I aim for.

How can I do that in GeoTools?

See figure below.

[image]